# Поясните смысл выражения "смертный лик"

Tags: значение-слов

Смертный лик - что это? Лик смерти? Или другое?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445610/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, "смертный лик" может относиться к разным ликам, связанным со смертью, как живым (на пороге смерти, с печатью смерти на лице), так и мертвым.

Лик смерти? Что под этим понимать? Лицо смерти-старухи с клюкой? Не думаю, что его можно назвать смертным ликом. Отпечаток будущей смерти на лице живого человека? И тут не думаю, что его можно назвать смертным ликом.

> Пред нашим бруствером чужой мертвец лежал:
>   Его то солнце жгло, то ветер охлаждал.
>   Я **смертный лик** его разглядывал стократ,
>   И мне все чудилось, что там лежит мой брат.
>   (Нева, 2015 №2, http://magazines.russ.ru/neva/2015/2/17z.html)
>
> Дядя Ваня в его спектакле умирает. Соня гримирует **смертный лик** героя: открывает ему глаза, лепит из охладевших уст дяди нелепую улыбку. (Ольга Галахова, театральный критик, главный редактор газеты «Дом актера», специально для РИА Новости. РИА Новости https://ria.ru/analytics/20090904/183674588.html)
>
> Я умирал. Ты расцветала.
>   И вдруг, взглянув на смертный лик,
>   В чертах угасших угадала,
>   Что эта смерть — бессильный крик…   (Блок)

В "чертах угасших" — человек умер или на пороге смерти.

А это как понимать:

> Затмился **смертный лик луны-богини**
>
> Туманом смешан цвета крик
>   И будоражит холодовье,
>   И хрупкость светлая - на миг,
>   На вздох, на всхлип у изголовья, -
>   Замкнула мир дремотной знобью,
>   Покуда **солнца смертный лик**
>   Не обратил прозрачной кровью

Возможно, луна похожа на лицо мертвеца, а солнце умирает в конце дня.

Answer (score 2):

> Я умирал. Ты расцветала.
>
> И вдруг, взглянув на смертный лик,
>
> В чертах угасших угадала,
>
> Что эта смерть — бессильный крик…
>
> ---
>
> Смири же позднюю тревогу;
>
> И я под осень дней моих,
>
> Как лист, упавший на дорогу,
>
> Смешаюсь с прахом остальных…
>
> ---
>
> 27 января 1900

---

Из этих блоковских строк понятно, что речь о лице умирающего, - что ещё требуется добавить в пояснение?

У Плутарха - иное:

> Свой образ божества сменив на смертный лик,
>
> Узрел он Дирки ключ и ток Исменских вод.

Полагаю, что у него речь об облике простого смертного (в противовес божеству).

Та же цитата, но ложно приписанная Еврипиду (с попыткой толкования):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, как ни крути, а есть прямое и образное толкование: смертный лик - лицо умирающего или лицо смертного.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно. Получается, что "смертный лик" относится к ещё живому человеку)

Comment: Лия, здесь "спасибо" выражают кликом по верхнему треугольничку и по нижней галочке. Если Вы, конечно, не ждёте принципиально иных ответов. )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova неэтично просить нажать на галочку! Воздержитесь, пожалуйста. Может автору вопроса необходимы еще ответы.