# Значение выражения "лик смерти"

Tags: значение-слов

Как понимать "лик смерти"? Это лицо человека или условное "лицо" мистической субстанции под названием "смерть", проступающее сквозь черты человеческого лица?

Варианты:

- лицо мертвого человека
- синоним "смертного лика" (см. [Поясните смысл выражения "смертный лик"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445597/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba))
- лицо смерти-старухи с косой
- нечто связанное со смертью, проступающее сквозь черты человеческого лица.

Заметим, что есть три разных выражения: лик смерти, лицо смерти и смертный лик (см. [Поясните смысл выражения "смертный лик"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445597/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba)). Можно их четко разделить? *Лик смерти* и *лицо смерти* (в выражениях "перед лицом смерти" и "смотреть в лицо смерти") — разные понятия?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445597/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba

Answer (score 1):

**"Лик смерти"** - это лицо той самой старухи с косой (или иных метафизических существ, в зависимости от различий в религиозно-культурных традицях).
Все остальные предложенные варианты (касающиеся умирающего) - это все-таки **"смертный лик"**.

Answer (score 0):

Важные ссылки на великих из «Заповедей Мераба» Игоря Ларина («Звезда», 2003):

> Кант называл это «раскаянием совести», неразрешимым нашими чувствами,
>   бессильными перед необходимостью повернуть мир вспять. Об этом хорошо
>   знали древние, увязывавшие акты мыслей с временным разрывом, некой
>   остановкой в действии, дрейфом, сносящим нас к судьбе.
>
> Платон называл это «обратным плаванием», подразумевая некое движение
>   от смерти к жизни как единственно позволяющее на миг схватить момент
>   истинности своего положения. Лик смерти есть один из невыразимых
>   символов, концентрирующих наше сознание в некой точке, открывшейся
>   вдруг завершенной гармонией. Это своего рода прожектор, выхватывающий
>   опосредованный косвенный облик нас самих. Его скользнувший свет,
>   точнее ― огонь, лизнувший нас, рождает тайну, которая оказывается
>   фундаментальным условием понимания других вещей.

У Платона всё настолько ясно, что не требует пояснения. Собственное же понимание физической сути этой словоформы соотносится с мимолётным (пограничным) внутренним состоянием и отражением его в лице человека, который отходит в жизнь вечную. Не готовый, застигнутый врасплох и тот, кто успел отдать «долги наша», примириться и попрощаться, уйдут по-разному: в облике последнего, вероятно, будет проявлен и зафиксирован с благодарностью встреченный им в этот миг «светлый» лик смерти.